# bash - Change line by line Interactively

Tags: bash, shell-script, interactive

I am new in bash scripting. I want to create an interactive script which is prompt user to enter data for editing a file line by line.

The scenario:
- Read a file and iterate over each line, I use `for in`

- Ask user whether to edit the line or not
- If yes, do the editing
- If not, continue to the next line
- End the interaction after everything finish.

My approach:

```
# --> get file contents and convert them to an array
readarray thearray < ips.info

# --> Iterate the array and do interactive editing
for item in ${!thearray[@]}; do
 if [[ "$item" == 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "First line: ${thearray[$item]}. Change this line? (y/n)"
    read Useranswer
    if [ $Useranswer = y]; then
        echo "Please type any string:"
        read Firststring    
    elif [ $Useranswer = n]; then
        # not sure what to write here to resume 
    fi
fi
done
echo "Everything done!"
```

Is there any mistake in my code above and how to resume if the user press `n` on their keyboard?

Comment: are you really sure you want to edit the file line by line, of just the first line ?

Comment: this statement  `[ $Useranswer = n];` will throw an error, the closing `]` needs to have a space before it, i.e. ``[ $Useranswer = n ];``

Comment: If you want to edit the file interactively the best solution would probably be vim

Answer (score 2):

you can use the **no-op** command ( do nothing ) , in shell it is `:`

```
elif [ $Useranswer = n]; then
    : 
fi
```

otherwise you can use the `exit` command, which is used to terminate scripts. The command can have an exit status ranges from 0-255. Only `exit 0` means the success, every other exit status code describe some sort of failure (which is not what you need). Also, you could do as follow too :

```
elif [ $Useranswer = n]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

But in this case, the rest of the script will not be executed because exit really terminate the script in this point, so eg.: if user press "n" you will never get the output of `echo "Everything done!`

Comment: probably worth mentioning `break` (or `break 2` to break *both* the if and the for loop) as an alternative to `exit` as it will break the local block but allow the script to continue

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution:**

```
# --> get file contents and convert them to an array
readarray thearray < test1

# --> Iterate the array and do interactive editing
declare i=1;
#printf "%s\n" "${thearray[@]}"

while [ $i -le  ${#thearray[@]} ]; do
    echo $i
    echo -e "First line: ${thearray[$i]}. Change this line? (y/n)"
    read Useranswer
    if [ $Useranswer == "y" ]; then

        echo "Please type any string:"
        read Firststring
        thearray[$i]="${Firststring}"
        let i=$i+1
    elif [ $Useranswer == "n" ]; then
        let i=$i+1
        echo $i
    fi
done
echo "printing results\n"
printf "%s\n" "${thearray[@]}"

echo "Everything done!"
```

I keept the `readarray` which is pretty obvious and running well.

I then declare `i` and set it to 1 and it will help me to loop into the array.

I then use a `while` loop, iterating until `i` is not more lower or equal to the size of the array `${#thearray[@]}`.

your syntax `${!thearray[@]}` is not correct because it is used for associative array to get the list of the whole associated value. It's not working on indexed array.

Then i display the prompt to change the current element of array[$i]. 
If answer is yes, than i read the answer and set the array[$i] to this value 
And i increase by one my `i`. 
If no, i just increase by 1 `i`.

when exiting the loop, i display again the array to show the change.

You can save it back to original back if you want to save it.

Comment: what shell are you using? `${!thearray[@]}` works for me on bash

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you have asked

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# --> get file contents and convert them to an array
readarray thearray < ips.info

# --> Iterate the array and do interactive editing

for item in ${!thearray[@]}; do
    echo "Line number: "$item
    echo "line contents: "${thearray[$item]}
    echo -n "Change this line? (y/n)"
    read Useranswer
    if [ $Useranswer = y ]; then
        echo -n "Please type any string:"
        read Firststring
        # insert new value into array
        thearray[$item]=$Firststring
    elif [ $Useranswer = n ]; then
        # not sure what to write here to resume 
        :
    fi
done
declare -p thearray
echo "Everything done!"
```